# How to get the number of Closed Bug and Open Bug for a specific user story in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

I want to get the number of Open Bug and number of Closed Bug for a specific User Story ID in TFS using C#

Comment: What's the version of your TFS?

Comment: What's the result after trying my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these steps:

1. Create a query like this:

[image]

2. Create an application through Visual Studio (e.g. console app)
3. Install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient nugget Package

Sample code

```
var u = new Uri("collection url");
            string projectName = "project";
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"))); 
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
           var query= workitemClient.GetQueryAsync(projectName, "Shared Queries/BugInUserStory").Result;
          var result=  workitemClient.QueryByIdAsync(query.Id).Result;
            var totalCounts = result.WorkItemRelations.Count(); //included User Story
```